# How do I achieve conditional routing based on the parameter in the requested route?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, router

I am developing a React js blog-like web site and I am finding some trouble managing the routes. My pages with articles' URLs are like this: website/pages/3

I would like to redirect to homepage when the page index is 1, since the homepage is the first page with articles by default. 
My Router looks like this:

```jsx
<Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Page postsPerPage={3}/>} />
          <Route exact path="/Page/:activePage" render={() => <Page postsPerPage={3}/>} />
          <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/AddPost" component={AddPost}  />
          <Route path="/:postLocation" component={Post}  />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```

I would like to route "/Page/:activePage" to the component the route "/" renders if the activePage is 1. So the component would be the same (Page), but the path would be different.

Could conditional rendering in the Router do the trick, and if so, how? I was thinking about something along these lines:

```
 <Route exact path="/Page/:activePage" render={() => 
         {
            let {activePage} = useParams()
            if (activePage == 1) return (<Redirect to="/"/>)
            else return(<Page  postsPerPage={3}/>) 
          } 
          }/>
```

However it seems React is not happy about me using useParams there (there's a compilation error:  React Hook "useParams" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)

I tested that snippet with a constant value of 1 instead of the activePage parameter and it does redirect so that basically leaves me with the question of how do I retrieve the parameter from the path?

Comment: Sounds like you should handle the redirect in the `<Page>` component rather than an inline render function.

Comment: Huh. Didn't even think of this, will try. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render function in this case The render prop function has access to all the same route props (match, location and history) as the component render prop.
so you can basically do something like.

```
 <Route exact path="/Page/:activePage" render={(props) => 
         {
            if (props.match.params.activePage == 1) return (<Redirect to="/"/>)
            else return(<Page  postsPerPage={3}/>) 
          } 
      }
/>
```

Looking at your example case above, I will rather not redirect anything but carry the logic into the Page component. inside the componentDidMount or useEffect function that extracts the activePage param. I will check if it's 1(or whatever sentinal value you choose to use) Then I perform the logic that will have been performed by the home component else I proceed normally with the route. eg If you extracted it and do a fetch to the backend for the case where its, not 1, then when it's 1 you could just return from the function and it will work as if it were on the home page. alternatively, after the check, if it's 1 you could then redirect back to '/'.

Answer (score 1):

The render function of Component the  is called with three parameters namely match, history and location. You can use them to perform the action you are trying to do with hooks.

```
<Route ... render={({match}) => {
 if (match.params.activePage == 1) {
  doYourStuff()
 }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably handle the routing within your Pages component or if you prefer, create a separate component to handle the conditional routing.

for example:

```
function Pages (props) {

    const {activePage} = useParams()

    return activePage === 1 ? <Redirect to='/' /> : (
<div>
Your Pages component content here
</div>

)
}

export default Pages;
```

or

```
function ConditionalRoutingComponent(props) {

    const {activePage} = useParams()

    return activePage === 1 ? <Redirect to='/' /> : <Page  postsPerPage={3}/>
}

export default ConditionalRoutingComponent;
```

Hope this helps